# Template refs remain null with TS in Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, ref

I have a parent component Images.vue with 3 child components ImagesGridArea1, ImagesGridArea2 and ImagesGridArea3. Children tags like this: `<ImagesGridArea1 ref="ref1" :key="ref1key" ... />`. Parent script: `const ref1 = ref(null);` Nothing special.

Problem is: if I use v-if to load only nesessary child, refs work fine in JS, but only first ref (for default child component) works in TS. ref2 and ref3 remains null.

Ofk, they work if I change it to v-show, at least with functon ref like this: `<ImagesGridArea2 :ref="(el) => {ref2=el as ComponentPublicInstance}" :key="ref2key" ... />`. But I'd really like to keep them unmounted, if not in use.

Can I somehow get an instance refs of children without keeping them mounted (v-if)?

Comment: If it's not mounted, then you can't possibly reference it because it doesn't exist. If you need to access the component right after switching the condition that shows the component, then use [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) in order to wait for the component to be mounted before accessing the ref

Comment: But how do I reference them in the first place? So my ref2 and ref3 contain objects, not initial nulls.

Comment: Or I'd better use a <component is> tag?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it using a `<component>` tag with ref. Still don't understand why it worked earlier with JS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).